# Decision rule to use docker-machine or not on docker run

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When I use docker-machine in a Windows environment (installed with docker-toolbox), every `docker run` command uses that docker-machine as the docker daemon.
However, when I use docker-machine in a Linux environment, which has native docker daemon installed along with docker-machine, `docker run` command uses native docker daemon even if there is a running docker-machine instance.

Questions are:

- How does `docker run` command decide which daemon to use?
- Are there any method to list running containers on a docker-machine instance?

For the second one, I know I can SSH to the docker-machine instance and query `docker ps` in it, but I want check it from outside the instance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker Machine stack works by firing up a VM, and then setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to point at it.  In particular, it also does the required setup to TLS-encrypt the connection and to set up a TLS client certificate to authenticate the caller.  (Without this setup, a remote `DOCKER_HOST` is extremely dangerous.)

So: `docker run` and every other Docker command uses the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to decide where to run things.  If `DOCKER_HOST` points at a Docker Machine VM, `docker ps` will list the containers there; you won’t usually need to `docker-machine ssh` (though it’s a useful tool when you really need it).

On a native Linux host it’s far easier to just directly use a local Docker daemon.  If you do have both a local daemon and a docker-machine VM, you can

```sh
# switch to the Docker Machine VM
eval $(docker-machine env default)

# switch back to the host Docker
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Thank you very much!